# Como dividir Arquivos em c++

Tags: c++

Estou começando meus estudos em c++, e não estou conseguindo dividir em arquivos diferentes, se puderem me ajudem

Código principal

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Celular.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Celular motorola();
   motorola.ligar();
  return 0;
}
```

Meu arquivo ponto.h

```
class Celular
{
 public:
    void ligar();
}
```

Meu arquivo cpp, que implementa a funão

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "Celular.h"
 using namespace std;

 Celular:: void ligar()
 {
    cout << "consegui" >>;
 }
```

No main principal aparece esse erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que os 3 arquivos estão na mesma pasta[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Hã!? `cout << "consegui" >>;`!? Acho que esse `>>` não deveria estar aí. Ou melhor, use `cout << "consegui" << endl;`

Comment: É eu me confundi, é só como teste, estou começando hoje

Comment: O erro não parece ter a ver com separar arquivos, e a pergunta está sem informações relevantes para pode r ajudar, colco que os nomes de todos os arquivos, inclusive os que não aparecem aí no código. Pode ser só distração e erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua divisão de arquivos está correta, porém alguns detalhes devem ser observados:

Sua classe `Celular` não possui *nenhum* construtor. No código principal, você tenta instânciar a classe `Celular` por meio de um construtor que não existe!

Altere seu código principal para:

```
#include "Celular.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Celular motorola; //Removido a chamada do construtor
   motorola.ligar();
  return 0;
}
```

No seu arquivo `.h`, a definição da classe `Celular` não possui `;` (ponto-e-vírgula) no final e também não possui sentinelas para evitar redeclarações durante a etapa de compilação.

Seu arquivo `.h` deveria ser algo como:

```
#ifndef CELULAR_H
#define CELULAR_H

class Celular
{
    public:
        void ligar();
};

#endif
```

E, finalmente, seu arquivo `.cpp`, contendo a implementação da classe `Celular`, comete dois erros de sintaxe, que corrigidos fariam o arquivo se parecer com isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Celular.h"

using namespace std;

void Celular::ligar()   //O tipo de retorno estava no lugar errado!
{
   cout << "consegui" << endl;   //Havia um erro de sintaxe aqui!
}
```